# No response being sent from ajax request when using require

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, header, require

I have a php page , send.php that is successfuly echoing out an array when I go to that page.  However When i try to use ajax on index.php to access that page there is no response.

This the page I am accessing 
send.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$json = array(
    "test" => null,
    "success" => null,
    "urls" => null,
); 
$json = array("hi" => null, "success" => null);
$class = new test();
$json["success"] = true;
$json["hi"] = $class->_array;   
echo json_encode($json);


class test{
    public $_array = array();
    public $urlPreArray;    
    public $sensoredArray;

    function __construct(){
        require_once('./mysqlDB.php'); //this causes nothing to be sent back
        $cookieString = $_COOKIE['crUrl'];
        $this->_array = explode(",", $cookieString);    
    }
}
```

This is my index page

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery1.11.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script> 
    function load(){    
        $.get("./php/send.php",
        {
             action:"displayUrlsNotes"
        },
        function(data, status){
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        }, "json");
        console.log("end");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='load();'>Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If I go to send.php in my browser it works and the array is printed, but when I go to index.php and press the button the ajax request is made successfuly but nothing is sent back.

It does work if I comment out require_once('./mysqlDB.php'); in send.php

I am new to using classes in php and wansn't sure what exactly I needed to google to find an answer.

Comment: where is your mysqlDB.php inside a folder or with index.php path?

Comment: I have index.php and a folder called php.  mysqlDB.php and send.php are in the php folder.  I don't believe it's a directory issue because I placed the mysqlDB.php in the same folder as index.php and that didn't solve it.  Also if that was the issue I would think I would get an error when going to send.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The problem was I had html code on my mysqlDB.php page.  Thanks for telling me to look into my file structure.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is to do with your folder structure.

You have used a relative path to include your database file. It is better practice to use the full path, then you can call the script from any context without any problem.

I would suggest something like:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysqlDB.php');
```

or you can define the root as a constant in a common config file:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', '/home/mysite/public_html');
require_once(ROOT_DIR.'/mysqlDB.php');
```